# Cannot update a field to a Lookup, MasterDetail, or Hierarchy from something else (44:13)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

For Push and Deploy Lightning Web Component Files module of Lightning Web Components basics, when I try to deploy from the scratch org to Dev org, it gives me the following error :

**Cannot update a field to a Lookup, MasterDetail, or Hierarchy from something else (44:13)**

for the project path : force-app\main\default\objects\Case\fields\Product__c.field-meta.xml

[image]

It's a new trailhead playground that I created, so the initial config for both scratch and dev orgs must be same. And therefore, if it works in scratch org, then ideally the deployment should not fail.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A playground is more like a devOrg than a scratch org - it has some included metadata. This specific issue is covered in the [instructions](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc#installing-e-bikes-using-a-developer-edition-org):

> 4. In **Setup**, under **Object Manager**, delete the custom **Product** picklist field from the **Case** object.

DevOrgs (and TH playgrounds) come with a Case.Product__c field that is a picklist. The E-Bikes app has a field with the same API name on Case, but it is a lookup. You have to delete the picklist before the Lookup will deploy.